# how to change the name in the "cancel and return to" link on the express checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

i'm creating a small marketplace where several sellers can sell their products and each has their own express checkout link, depending on their email.

my form is like this:

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="form_paypal">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="wa_dw_2.0.4">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="receiver@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver_email" value="receiver@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="123.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.me.com/return.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Title Goes Here">
    <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="12345">
    <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to MY WEBSITE NAME">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.me.com/failure.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.me.com/notify.php">
    </form>
```

note that i set the "cbt" value as per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/ but it's not working :( the return link still shows

```
"cancel and return to receiver@gmail.com"
```

which is confusing and just plain ugly for the buyer.

any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

it's the same on the sandbox or the live version, i might add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document says "**cbt : Sets the text for the Return to Merchant button on the PayPal Payment Complete page.For Business accounts, the return button displays your business name in place of the word "Merchant" by default.** " This means you will see this text on the PayPal thank you page after the buyer completes the payments . Something like below :
[image]

Comment: That makes sense! I guess I was completely understanding the feature wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you're using here is Payments Standard, not Express Checkout.  Eshan is correct with the information he provided regarding the parameter you're working with...it doesn't come up until after the payment is completed.

If you were actually using Express Checkout you would indeed have control over what you're asking about via the BRANDNAME parameter.  It would still say "Cancel and return to" but then whatever you set for BRANDNAME would get output after that.

To my knowledge Payments Standard does not give you access to adjust the cancel link like EC does.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into using Express Checkout instead :)